# Add or extend Vuex action types using Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm somewhat new to Typescript. I'm trying to add specific type structure to every single Actions I declare in Vue store without repeating them in every single Vuex module files.

**For example, I can do this in every action in every store files like below:**

```js
// This will be declared as global interface.
interface ReturnObject {
   status: boolean;
   msg: string;
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
   actions: {
      // I'd need to write every single action this way..
      exampleAction: async (context, payload): Promise<ReturnObject> => {
         return { status: true, msg: 'Hello World!' }
      },
   },
   modules: {
      // Appling to all module file's actions as well.
   }
})
```

But I want to do this:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
   actions: {
      // Types are automatically applied.
      async exampleAction(context, payload) {
         return {status: true, msg: 'Hello World!'}
      }
   },
   modules: {
      // Appling to all module file's actions as well.
   }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do you want every action to return `ReturnObject`?

Comment: @caTS I wanted all actions to return in specific structure.

Comment: Which types? Return type? Actions can't return anything but `Promise<void>`

Comment: @EstusFlask I want to set return type to maybe `Promise<number>` or in my case `Promise<ReturnObject>` as indicated above.

Comment: You can't. Check how Vuex works. Actions don't return data

Comment: @EstusFlask ..? What do you mean..? I always return values in actions.. [Check this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions)

Comment: It's already stated above, it's `Promise<void>`. You can return a promise of `undefined`, not arbitrary value like you're trying. You can notice that in examples it's `dispatch('actionA').then(() =>` You can't read a value from an action in `then`

Comment: @EstusFlask No you are wrong. Using `async await` you are able wait for the return value after triggering dispatch. Even in Vue typescript the action's return type is `any`.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected, I remember it was possible at some point, not sure if it still is. Any way, this is not a common use for a store. Actions are primarily needed to operate on a state, not return a result. I don't think it's possible without modifying Vuex typings globally, which is a bad thing. You can always use your own helper like createActions that will do any modifications to action functions - either type or runtime

Comment: @EstusFlask I definitely don't want to touch `node_modules` folder at all. I just want to find a way to declare global type for Vue actions. The reason why I'm posting this question is because I'm lacking on TypeScript so I might be missing a way to fully utilize it with Vue. I understand about JS and Vue well so those are not the issues for me.

Comment: This isn't about modifying source files, it's about extending types like that, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation . Can't say how it will be in case of Vuex. I meant that modifying original global behaviour for local purposes is universally a bad practice, not only in TS. I'd definitely use custom helpers like createStore or createActions that enforce types for `actions`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248814/discussion-between-passionatelearner-and-estus-flask).

Comment: @EstusFlask So can you post an answer on those? Would like to see example code.

Comment: I posted an example. Cannot confirm if it works but I'd expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying original global behaviour for local purposes is universally a bad practice.  A possible solution is to use custom helpers to extend it instead of modifying it. In this case it's a simple wrapper that extends [original store types](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/main/types/index.d.ts#L13):

```
type CustomActionHandler<S, R> = (this: Store<R>, injectee: ActionContext<S, R>, payload?: any) => ReturnObject | Promise<ReturnObject>;

interface CustomActionTree<S, R> {
  [key: string]: CustomActionHandler;
}

interface CustomModule<S, R> extends Module<S, R> {
  actions?: CustomActionTree<S, R>;
}

export interface CustomModuleTree<R> {
  [key: string]: CustomModule<any, R>;
}

interface CustomStoreOptions<S> extends StoreOptions<S> {
  actions?: CustomActionTree<S, S>;
  modules?: CustomModuleTree<S>;
}

function createCustomStore<S>(options: CustomStoreOptions<S>) {
  return new Store(options);
}
```